# jquery / php - send to phone ( txt / email ) change the FRM sender

Tags: php, jquery, email

I have a site up I am building right now and looking on seeing if I can make the email look better.

I have a "send to phone" option on this site - enter in your cell, choose the carrier - hit send.

Everything looks fine - I am sending a message with the restaurant information - but the From on top line reads `anonymous@messtudios.com`. `messtudios.com` is the dedicated hosting server all my clients website sit under. Can I change the From address to something like `info@phillysandcream.com` or something else?

I'm using PHP's `mail()` function to send the message.

Comment: It's funny that you post this -- I'm from around this area of NY. I guess I have to pay a visit now!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `From:` header:

```
$header = "From: info@phillysandcream.com";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Source [`PHP: mail - Manual`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3470).